# KDE Confidence Interval

Tags: python, probability, kde-plasma, ecdf

Can anyone help with below code?[image: Please see the plot below I was trying to find the lower and upper limit of the distribution.]

My code as below

## In[152]:

```
sample = kde.resample(43826)
5 ** np.percentile(sample, 5)
```

## In[153]:

```
 def resample_kde_percentile(kde):
    sample = kde.resample(kde.n)
    return 5 ** np.percentile(sample, 5)
```

## In[154]:

```
def summarize(t, digits=2):
     table = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Estimate', 'SE', 'CI90'])
     est = np.mean(t).round(digits)
     SE = np.std(t).round(digits)
     CI95 = np.percentile(t, [5, 95]).round(digits)
     table.loc[''] = est, SE, CI95
     return table
```

## In[155]:

```
t10 = [resample_kde_percentile(kde)
   for i in range(1000)]

summary10 = summarize(t10)
summary10
```

I am trying to find the upper and lower limit using KDE bootstrapping.

steps

1. Find residual of Actual and prediction.
2. Normalize the residuals
3. KDE of residuals
4. resampling  KDE
5. find the upper and lower limit
6. create Prediction interval.

Comment: how do you import/define `kde`? post the whole code

Comment: from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
   kde = gaussian_kde(NR)
    n = TEST=df1['SUM_TEST'].notna().sum()

sample = kde.resample(43826)
5 ** np.percentile(sample, 5)

......

Comment: Where NR is normalized data

Comment: Example paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1568494622002563#fd5